# Spatial Intersection of Point with lines in SQL

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-query

I am trying to join two spatial tables in SQL.

One table has point information as below - **(Point Table)**

[image]

Another table has line information as below - **(Line Table)**

[image]

What I want to do is match the points from point table to the line on line table (based on intersection of point and line) and join the two tables to get hwy_link_id/hwycov_id corresponding to each station_id.

I am very new to spatial data in SQL and I would really appreciate if someone can suggest me a way to do it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did the below answer help you in any way?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some access issues with our database connection I was using to do all this is and that's why haven't yet tested what you suggested. I am waiting at this point and as soon as I test this and it works, I will officially thank you :)

Comment: No problem.  I was more concerned at my attempt on a MySQL query with no experience using it! :-)

Comment: If MySQL is new to you, and heck even if it isn't, download MySQL Workbench .. trust me .. if you aren't using it, its like doing an excel file in a text document, versus just right click a couple times and be done with everything.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can just use the geography / geometry types' STIntersects method as part of the join.  Assuming you can do this in MySQL too (I do not use MySQL so cannot test), the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
points.station_id,
lines.hwy_link_id,
lines.hwycov_id
FROM
points
LEFT JOIN
lines ON (STIntersects(points.Shape, lines.Shape) = 1);
```

That said, unless your data is hyper-accurate, lines and points may not intersect when you would expect them to.  It would therefore be advisable to add a small buffer around either the points or the lines to give the Intersection a small distance to play with (catering for coordinate value type rounding etc.).

The query would therefore change to something like:

```
SELECT
points.station_id,
lines.hwy_link_id,
lines.hwycov_id
FROM
points
LEFT JOIN
lines ON (ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(points.Shape, 10), lines.Shape) = 1);
```

I'm not sure on the MySQL units for geography / geometry but I expect they are metres.

References:

ST_Intersects: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-intersects

ST_Buffer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer

Comment: I tried what you suggested but with modification to try and get it to work on MySQL. Below is what I tried. Query runs successfully but does not return me anything.


`SELECT *`


`FROM points.stations, lines.hwy_link`


`WHERE station.shape.STIntersects(hwy_link.shape) = 1`

Any suggestions?

Comment: @ashishkul I don't know the intricacies of MySQL but where is your join in that statement? Is it inferred by the , between the tables??

Comment: I saw an example where STIntersects was used in a similar way. I am guessing that the FROM table1, table 2 is implicitly joining the two. As I mentioned, query runs successfully (without any rows returned) and I see that the header in the result windows has columns from both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

For SQLServer the query really should be:

```
SELECT
points.station_id
FROM
points
RIGHT JOIN
lines ON points.shape.STIntersects(lines.shape.STBuffer(0.0005))=1
where lines.hwy_link_id=1
```

In the above I chose a single line referenced by an id=1 stored in my table. To test with one line at a time. You can remove this if need be.

Note: we thicken the line with a buffer and seeing if that thicker line intersects with points. If you have too many points you reduce the buffer for geometries way below 1 - so this figure used here represents around 50m thickening in geospatial size. Try different numbers.

You could of course turn this round and buffer the points instead of the line. Experiment.

Comment: But OP said he is using MySQL not SQL Server.